# Flutter Offline app with Spring Boot as Backend using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, flutter, offline, offlineapps

Currently, I have a flutter app using Spring Boot Framework with MongoDB. I want to add **Offline** functionality to the application.

App Functionality:
User fills various forms(personal details, family member details, etc).

**Use Case**: When the user fills the Personal Details Form fields like 'name', 'dob' are filled manually and location (selected using the dropdown(GET APIs)).
The internet connection might be gone while filling these forms.

How can I make the application offline ready?

One way that I thought of is storing all the data using any local database like SQLite but there can more than 10 Forms so it can be difficult for maintaining a lot of data. Moreover, how the data will sync with Backend?

Questions:
How to store data?
How to sync store data with Backend when the app comes Online?

Is there any other better approach to achieve this task?

Comment: Do you ask same in flutter discord- https://discord.gg/ujeg3M and https://discord.gg/fCphxM